# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float in heapsort

Tags: python

I can't find my mistake in here, if someone can help me would be great.

```
def heapsort (lista) :
    n= len(lista)-1
    k= n/2 
    while (k>0) :
        downheap(lista,n,k) 
        k-=1 
    while (n>=0) :
        (lista[1]),(lista[n])=(lista[n]),(lista[1]) 
        n-=1 
        return downheap(lista, n, 1) 
    return lista  

def downheap (lista, n, k) :
    v= lista[k] 
    while (k<=(n/2)) :
        j=k+k
        if (j<n and (lista[j]) == (lista[j])) :
            break
        (lista[k]) = (lista[j]) 
        k = j 
    lista[k] = v
```

Error:

```
>>> heapsort([4,2,3,1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in heapsort
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in downheap
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

Comment: Is this Python 3 perhaps? Python errors come with a full traceback, do  include that when you ask about a Python problem.

Comment: And how would we go about reproducing your error? How do you call `heapsort()`, such that it triggers the exception?

Comment: I was able to guess, *this time*. But for future questions, include a small sample of code that lets us reproduce your problem.

Comment: Note that your code, as posted, contains a syntax error too, as the last `if` statement is missing a closing parenthesis. You have too many of those as it is, really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3, using the `/` division operator *always returns a `float` value*:

```
>>> 2/2
1.0
>>> 3/2
1.5
```

Use floor division instead, the `//` operator:

```
k = n // 2
```

The `//` operator always returns an integer, flooring the result:

```
>>> 2//2
1
>>> 3//2
1
```

Perhaps you coded your functions from an example in Python 2; in Python 2 the `/` operator is an ambiguous operator; it'll act like the floor division operator when both operands are integers, but if either operand is a float, then suddenly it behaves differently and returns floating point division results *instead*. Because both operands in your code are integers, in Python 2 your code would not have thrown that exception.

Your next problem is that `downheap()` does not return anything, so when you use `return downheap(lista, n, 1)` in `heapsort()` you'll return `None`. I suspect that the `return` there is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When dividing just cast to int

```
def heapsort (lista) :
    n= len(lista)-1
    k= int(n/2)                       // instead of k= n/2 
    while (k>0) :
        downheap(lista,n,k) 
        k-=1 
    while (n>=0) :
        (lista[1]),(lista[n])=(lista[n]),(lista[1]) 
        n-=1 
        return downheap(lista, n, 1) 
    return lista
```